# Calling C# COM Component From Unmanaged C++ Remotely?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dcom

I wrote a C# .NET COM component which is then called from a C# front end. However, it also needs to work from an old Visual C++ 6 client app too. This works fine when it is all installed on the same machine but I need to call it remotely. This fails with a class not registered error. The server where the component is installed is a Windows 7 64bit machine and the client is 32bit XP if that makes any difference. Because my code was quite complex, I found a simple example on the internet. It's basically the same code as mine but fails in exactly the same way. The example is here :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12673/Calling-Managed-NET-C-COM-Objects-from-Unmanaged-C

That example client works fine on the same machine. I changed the client code to this (to run it remotely):

```
CoInitialize(NULL);

COSERVERINFO si; 
MULTI_QI qi; 
COAUTHINFO cai = { RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, 0, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,0, EOAC_NONE };
si.dwReserved1 = 0; 
si.pwszName =L"{machine name}"; 
si.pAuthInfo = &cai; 
si.dwReserved2 = 0; 

qi.pIID = &MyInterop::IID_IMyDotNetInterface; 
qi.pItf = NULL;
qi.hr = 1; 

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstanceEx(MyInterop::CLSID_MyDotNetClass,NULL,CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER ,&si,1,&qi);//CLSCTX_SERVER

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    MyInterop::IMyDotNetInterfacePtr* pCom = new MyInterop::IMyDotNetInterfacePtr;

    pCom->Attach((MyInterop::IMyDotNetInterface*)qi.pItf);


    HRESULT hRes = (*pCom)->ShowCOMDialog();

    delete pCom;

}

CoUninitialize();
```

However, it fails on the CoCreateInstanceEx with a HRESULT of 0x80040154 (Class not registered). The same client code above works fine when remotely calling a COM component written in Visual C++ 6.

Any ideas why this fails?

Comment: That comment helps why? As I say I know DCOM. I have written plenty of DCOM component in C++ and called them remotely with the same code as above. It's only this C# one that doesn't work.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is when I write DCOM components in C++ I have a proxy/stub dll which I don't have when I write this C# component. I'm wondering if C# supports DCOM calls from an unmanaged C++ client.